# django: don't log out when there is an error in view with `request.session.set_exipry`

Tags: python, django, error-handling

I'm currently developing an app with django, and every time I have an error when rendering a view or a template, my session gets logged out. This ends up being pretty annoying. How do I disable this 'feature'? Note that I don't get logged out if there's an error when the code is loaded/parsed (e.g. if a decorator on a view fails), only if there's an error within a view.

EDIT: I just tested and yes, `raise Exception` in a view does cause this.

All my views are wrapped with a decorator, which, among other things, does:

```
def needs_base_index_dict(func):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.session.set_expiry(30*60)
        #...
```

If I comment out the `set_expiry` line, then I don't get this behavior. When I fix errors, I am still logged in. If that line is not commented out, then any error in a view - including `raise Exception()` - logs the session out.

Comment: I have never heard of this "feature" - you might want to look into why this is happening at all... Are you suggesting `raise Exception` in a view causes this? Dynamic template errors don't cause this behavior for me either (say a file doesn't exist and I get an IOError)

Comment: Which session backend are you using? The default db-backend? Also, have you checked is the cookie present in the http headers of the error page or not?

Comment: @Jyrsa: i haven't changed anything explicitly so I presume it's using the default. how do I check?

Comment: If you haven't set anything then it's the default. Check SESSION_ENGINE. The default is django.contrib.sessions.backends.db. Note the second question above about the set-cookie header in the error page.

Comment: @Jyrsa: I don't have a `SESSION_ENGINE` variable in my `settings.py` so it is surely the default. as for the 2nd question, according to google chrome, the cookie is present in the request header but no cookie header is sent in the response header. but no cookie header is sent for non-error pages, either... the good pages have `Vary:Cookie, Accept-Encoding` whereas the error pages don't, though, is that what you meant?

Comment: @Claudiu: OK. The Vary:Cookie is a caching directive for proxies. Have you checked the value of the session using e.g. the shell of manage.py? Just look up the session ID of the Cookie and search for that as pk in django.contrib.sessions.models.Session edit:too fast enter button

Comment: @Jyrsa: oh my apologies, I had disabled it when i tested. yes, there is a `set-cookie` in the error response, for example: `Set-Cookie:sessionid=6f776b4b566a12affc321c73a93d4f82; expires=Mon, 09-Jul-2012 22:37:13 GMT; Max-Age=1800; Path=/`. the `expires` is 30 minutes past the time i accessed the page

Comment: could you please give us the full code of the decorator?

Comment: What database backend are you using ? Do you have transaction management enabled ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django basically writes your session to the database everytime there is a change to it. Since you are updating your session state in the view decorator, this means that there should be a session write to the DB.

However, if you are on a database with transaction management then when your view fails your database write gets rolled back. However your session cookie expire time has been updated on your browser. This means that your browser session and the session stored on the server no longer match. This inconsistency leads to the session being dropped and you being logged out.

This also explains why it works alright when you comment out that line.

If you use django dev server then you should be able to see your queries in the console. See if the session update query is running successfully when an error occurs. If not, you'll know why you are getting logged out :)

This is desired behavior but if you want to disable it in your debug environment, then just add a check for DEBUG above the relevant line in your decorator. Alternatively, you could disable transaction management (not recommended).

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer to why, but a workaround perhaps:

```
def needs_base_index_dict(func):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        #... do the work
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        #... then set the expiry
        request.session.set_expiry(30*60)
```

Comment: nice, this works. unless i guess there's an exception when rendering the template.

Answer (score 0):

You say in the comments that you get the set-cookie header in the error pages as well.
Does the session object look like it's ok? In the [sessions documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) it says that you can just access a db-based session like any other database object.

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
s = Session.objects.get(pk='2b1189a188b44ad18c35e113ac6ceead')
```

If that session is for an anonymous user then I'm willing to call this a very interesting feature. If it's a perfectly valid session but somehow it appears to you that you are no longer logged in, there is a bug in handling the session cookie.